# How do I handle Proxy Authentication with Selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy

[image: How do I handle this on Selenium using Java]

I've tried this code, but I doesn't do anything. Probably because it doesn't handle this kind of alert.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("asd");
// Handling Password alert
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("asd");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using Java robot class.

```
//set first variable in system clipboard
            StringSelection variable1 = new StringSelection("username");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(variable1,null);

            //use robot class to paste the content
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            //use robot class to enter tab, so the focus will be shifted in to next field
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

            //set second variable in system clipboard
            StringSelection variable2 = new StringSelection("password");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(variable2,null);

            //use robot class to paste the content
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

use robot class to press tab, so the focus will be shifted in to next field if it is ok button, use robot class to enter enter key other wise again use tab

```
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```